# VueJS Functional Components: Render arbitrary HTML

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a functional component that looks something like this:

```
export const TableCell = Vue.component('TableCell', {
  functional: true,
  render(createElement, context) {
    const item = context.props.item;
    const column = context.props.column as TableColumn;

    // Omitted: Render a template; value may have some basic HTML in it
    const value = ...;

    return createElement('span', value);
  },
  props: {
    item: Object,
    column: {}
  }
});
```

Obviously, `createElement` expects `value` to be text, not HTML (it seems to set the `innerText` property of the generated element. My question is twofold:

1. Is there a way to set `value` to the `innerHTML` of the `span`?
2. Is there a way to "recompile" it so that Vue components can be included in `value` (this is less important)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to answer my own question (the first part at least):

```
return createElement('span', {domProps: {innerHTML: value}});
```

This is documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth), but I somehow missed it.

Still looking for answers to my second question, if anyone has any suggestions.